# Canvas: Draw Lines on top of Filled Rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, lines

I have a function here that's supposed to draw a square and a plus sign in the middle, then reverse colors if the mouse is over it. It works fine if the mouse is not on top, but once it is filled, the plus sign disappears. I assume it's being covered up.

```
function drawAdd(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, mouse)
{
    var getID = document.getElementById("canvas_1");
    var color = "black";
    var px = cx + btnW/2;
    var py = cy + btnH/2;

    if (getID.getContext)
    {
        var ctx = getID.getContext("2d");

        ctx.clearRect(cx, cy, btnW, btnH);
        ctx.lineWidth = "10";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";

        if(mouse)
        {
            ctx.fillRect(cx, cy, btnW, btnH);
            color = "white";
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.strokeRect(cx, cy, btnW, btnH);
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = "20";
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.moveTo(px - 40, py);
        ctx.lineTo(px + 40, py);
        ctx.moveTo(px, py - 40);
        ctx.lineTo(px, py + 40);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `ctx.fillStyle = color` with `ctx.strokeStyle = color` as line color is set by strokeStyle, not fillStyle.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BhxtR/).